# Get memory consumption of variables during runtime in C++

Tags: c++, memory

Is there a debugging tool for a C++-program running on Linux to show the currently occupied memory for each active variable at a break point?

Reason for the question is: My program consumes quite a lot of memory, but I could not find out yet why. The general structure of the program looks as follows (untested, thus might contain errors):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
    private:
        int a, b;
        std::vector<double> data_list;
    public:
        A(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {
            //Todo: Fill data_list based on a and b
        };
        
        void fill_data(...);
        void retrieve_data(...);
}

class B {
    private:
        A class_A, class_AII;
    public:
        B(int i, int j) : class_A(A(i, j)),
        class_AII(A(i, j)) {
            //Do other stuff
        }
}

int main(void) {
    B class_B(5, 6);
    
    //How much memory is B consuming now, and how much goes to A and AII?
    return 0;
}
```

Of course I could add a `sizeof()` or a similar call to each variable, but is there an easier way to get a full overview? When profiling with Valgrind and Massif, I do not get that overview, only which allocator was responsible for how much memory.

Ideally the method would also be capable of analyzing the memory distribution on a Nvidia-GPU, but not necessarily.

Comment: "Of course I could add a sizeof() or a similar call to each variable" - ehh, no. That would just tell you the size of the *type*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I know, it was more meant as an illustration. I do not want to modify the code too much before testing/debugging, especially because modifying the code in debug might lead to different results compared to the release run.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, I currently do not use any debugger (except gdb if my program crashes, and I want to see the backtrace)

Comment: @arc_lupus If I understand where you're coming from, I've fixed your question. Technically, "debug option" is not wrong, but in that context "option" looks more like "command-line option" than "choice of which debugger to use".

Comment: Your problem here is C++ at a language level does not define the owned memory the way you want it to. The library defines the buffer allocated by the vector as owned by the vector and thus B, but at a language level that link isn't encoded in a way that allows any meaningful definition of the size of a variable other than the static size.

Comment: For example what would the size of an object containing a shared pointer to a vector be?

Comment: Hmm, I understand the problem @user1937198. Are there other methods/approaches to pinpoint within the code where my memory is increasing, and by how much?

Comment: Massifs allocation location is the common approach. That should tell you whats putting things into the vectors.

Comment: @user1937198: I.e. using --xtree-memory=full or similar options for massif?